# replace an expression of the form x*(string) with x copies of that string

Tags: vim, sed, substitution

I have some expressions of the form 3*(item1; item2; item3;), and I want to replace them with item1;item2;item3;item1;item2;item3;item1;item2;item3; (i.e. 3 lots of the thing in brackets, not including the brackets)

I can write a regex to extract the relevant parts, but I'm not sure how to do the other part -- I had a play around with submatch() and eval() but I've not found a way to concatenate a string to itself a specific number of times:

`:%s/\(\d+\)\*(\(\_[^)]\+\))/what goes here...?`

I had hoped something like \2{\1} would work, but that doesn't evaluate the number in braces. If I'm going about this the wrong way that's fine -- I'm not particularly tied to doing it this way, it's just what I sort of know, and I just wondered if it was easily possible in Vim.

Thanks if anyone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for custom function. You can use the built-in `repeat()` the same way.

`%s#\v(\d+)\*\((\_[^)]+)\)#\=repeat(submatch(2), submatch(1))#gc`

more info here `:help repeat()` and `:help function-list` for a list of built-in functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function that makes a repeated copy of a string ...

```
function! RepeatString(n,s)
  let l:result=""
  let l:n=a:n
  while l:n>0
    let l:result = l:result . a:s
    let l:n = l:n-1
  endwhile
  return l:result
endfunction
```

(note: this is very inefficient if n is large; it may well be that, e.g., making a list and calling `join` is more efficient) and then use the expression-evaluating feature of `:s` ...

```
:%s/\(\d\+\)\*(\([^)]\+\))/\=RepeatString(submatch(1),submatch(2))/g
```

(note: there are a couple of differences between my regexp and yours, which may be the results of typos in the original question).

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that. Regarding the differences, the ones I've noticed are an escaped +, which was a typo on my part (I guess it would confuse the issue if I correct it now), and I also had a \_ before the [^)] -- I probably should have removed that for this question, but my actual problem requires it, as the items can be on different lines. Thanks again!